# csv file in gridview need to be filtered for dates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a gridview loaded with csv file. I need to loop through time and date column so when user selects row that it will find next date and time in different row. So, that boss can see how many hours that person was working. I need to find total hours from "A02 - Rear Entrance( like logging in or clocking in) this loop needs to find last door left after 10 hour timespan. Please help.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public const string RearEntranceDoor = "AO2 - Rear Entrance";
    public const string ExteriorMainFloorDoor = "B12 - Exterior Main Floor Man Trap";
    public const string InteriorMainFloorDoor = "B12 - Interior Main Floor Man Trap";
    public const string RearBreakRoomDoor = "C13 - Rear Break Room Door";
    public const string ExteriorBasementDoor = "B02 - Exterior Basement Man Trap";
    public const string InteriorBasementDoor = "B02 - Interior Basement Man Trap";
    public const string ManagedServicesDoor = "D01 - Managed Services Main door";
    public const string ManagedServiceBigDoor = "D01 - Managed Services Big Door";
    public const  TimeSpan midnightShift = TimeSpan.Parse("20:00:00");
    public const TimeSpan midnightShift2 = TimeSpan.Parse("07:00:00");
    public const TimeSpan middayShift = TimeSpan.Parse("09:30:00");
    public const TimeSpan middayShift2 = TimeSpan.Parse("20:30:00");
    public const TimeSpan middayShift3 = TimeSpan.Parse("09:30:00");
    public const TimeSpan middayShift4 = TimeSpan.Parse("21:30:00");
    public const TimeSpan morningShift = TimeSpan.Parse("07:00:00");
    public const TimeSpan morningShift2 = TimeSpan.Parse("19:00:00");



    List<PersonEntered> peopleEntering;
    List<WorkSpan> workSpans;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       TurnOffLabelsandPanels();
        peopleEntering = new List<PersonEntered>();
        workSpans = new List<WorkSpan>();

    }


    private void csvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string delimiter = ",";
        string tablename = "Csvfile";
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        OpenFileDialog csvOpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        csvOpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        csvOpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        if (csvOpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to import the data from \n " + csvOpenFileDialog1.FileName + "?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                filename = csvOpenFileDialog1.FileName;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
                string csv = File.ReadAllText(csvOpenFileDialog1.FileName);


                string allData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] rows = allData.Split("\n".ToCharArray());


                bool header = true;


                foreach (string r in rows)
                {
                    string[] items = r.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());


                    if (header)
                    {
                        dataset.Tables.Add(tablename);
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[0]);//Sequence\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[1]);//Date and Time\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[2]);//Event message\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[3]);//Event number\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[4]);//Object #1\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[5]);//doors\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[6]);//Object #2\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[7]);//Employee name\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[8]);//Object #3\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[9]);//Description #3\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[10]);//Object #4\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[11]);//Description #4\\
                        dataset.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add(items[12]);//keycard\\



                        header = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(items[0]))
                        {
                            dataset.Tables[tablename].Rows.Add(items);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        string dateAndTime = dr["Date and Time"].ToString();
                        string personName = dr["Description #2"].ToString();
                        string doorType = dr["Description #1"].ToString();

                        DateTime dateEntered = Convert.ToDateTime(dateAndTime);
                        DoorType doorTypeEnum;

                        bool personExists = false;
                        foreach (object name in listboxOfNames.Items)
                        {
                            if (name.ToString() == personName)
                            {
                                personExists = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!personExists)
                        {
                            listboxOfNames.Items.Add(personName);
                        }
                        switch (doorType)
                        {
                            case "A02 - Rear Entrance":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearEntranceDoor;
                                break;
                            case "B12 - Exterior Main Floor Man Trap":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorMainFloorDoor;
                                break;
                            case "B12 - Interior Main Floor Man Trap":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorMainFloorDoor;
                                break;
                            case "C13 - Rear Break Room Door":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.RearBreakRoomDoor;
                                break;
                            case "B02 - Exterior Basement Man Trap":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor;
                                break;
                            case "B02 - Interior Basement Man Trap":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.InteriorBasementDoor;
                                break;
                            case "D01 - Managed Services Main door":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesDoor;
                                break;
                            case "D01 - Managed Services Big Door":
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.ManagedServicesBigDoor;
                                break;
                            default:
                                doorTypeEnum = DoorType.None;
                                break;
                        }



                        peopleEntering.Add(new PersonEntered(personName, dateEntered, doorTypeEnum));

                    }

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < peopleEntering.Count; i++)
                {
                    DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
                    DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
                    string personName = peopleEntering[i].PersonName;
                    if (peopleEntering[i].DoorEntered == DoorType.RearEntranceDoor)
                    {
                        startDate = peopleEntering[i].DateOfEntry;
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < peopleEntering.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (peopleEntering[j].DoorEntered == DoorType.ExteriorBasementDoor && peopleEntering[j].PersonName == personName)
                            {                                  

                                    endDate = peopleEntering[j].DateOfEntry;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    workSpans.Add(new WorkSpan(personName, startDate, endDate));
                }

                TurnOnLabels();
                this.csvGridView.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;


                MessageBox.Show(filename + " was successfully imported. \n ", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);


            }
            else
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

    }
    public string filename { get; set; }

    private void csvGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         int i;

             i = csvGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
             csvGridView.Columns[2].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[3].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[4].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[6].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[8].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[9].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[10].Visible = false;
             csvGridView.Columns[11].Visible = false;
             CsvInfoPanel.Visible = true;
             firstLastNameLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
             keyCardNumberLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
             timeDateEntryLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
             dateTimeDepartureLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[17].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
             DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(csvGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
             DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(csvGridView.Rows[17].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
             TimeSpan difference = endDate - startDate;
             keyedInHoursLbl.Text = 





        string personName = csvGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        List<WorkSpan> listOfWorkSpans = new List<WorkSpan>();

        for (int j = 0; j < workSpans.Count; j++)
        {
            if (workSpans[j].PersonName == personName)
            {
                listOfWorkSpans.Add(workSpans[j]);
            }
        }

    }

    private void listboxOfNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TurnOnPanel();

        string personName = listboxOfNames.Items[listboxOfNames.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        List<WorkSpan> listOfWorkSpan = new List<WorkSpan>();

        foreach (WorkSpan workSpan in workSpans)
        {
            if (workSpan.PersonName == personName)
            {
                listOfWorkSpan.Add(workSpan);


            }
        }
        int b;



         //create TimeSpan object

        b = csvGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        csvGridView.DataSource = listOfWorkSpan;
        firstLastNameLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[b].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        timeDateEntryLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[b].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dateTimeDepartureLbl.Text = csvGridView.Rows[b].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        DateTime startDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(csvGridView.Rows[b].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        DateTime endDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(csvGridView.Rows[b].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        TimeSpan difference = endDate - startDate;
        keyedInHoursLbl.Text = hoursOfShift.ToString();
    }

    private void TurnOnLabels()
    {
        csvGridView.Visible = true;
        EmployeeNameLbl.Visible = true;
        keycardLbl.Visible = true;
        dateTimeEntryLbl.Visible = true;
        dateTimeExitedLbl.Visible = true;
        hoursClockedInLbl.Visible = true;
        firstLastNameLbl.Visible = true;
        keyCardNumberLbl.Visible = true;
        timeDateEntryLbl.Visible = true;
        dateTimeDepartureLbl.Visible = true;
        keyedInHoursLbl.Visible = true;
        listboxOfNames.Visible = true;
        nameSelectionLbl.Visible = true;          

    }
    private void TurnOnPanel()
    {
        CsvInfoPanel.Visible = true;
        EmployeeNameLbl.Visible = true;
        dateTimeEntryLbl.Visible = true;
        dateTimeExitedLbl.Visible = true;
        firstLastNameLbl.Visible = true;
        timeDateEntryLbl.Visible = true;
        dateTimeDepartureLbl.Visible = true;
        keycardLbl.Visible = false;
        keyCardNumberLbl.Visible = false;
    }
    private void TurnOffLabelsandPanels()
    {
        csvGridView.Visible = false;
        EmployeeNameLbl.Visible = false;
        keycardLbl.Visible = false;
        dateTimeEntryLbl.Visible = false;
        dateTimeExitedLbl.Visible = false;
        hoursClockedInLbl.Visible = false;
        firstLastNameLbl.Visible = false;
        keyCardNumberLbl.Visible = false;
        timeDateEntryLbl.Visible = false;
        dateTimeDepartureLbl.Visible = false;
        keyedInHoursLbl.Visible = false;
        listboxOfNames.Visible = false;
        nameSelectionLbl.Visible = false;
        CsvInfoPanel.Visible = false;
    }
    private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


}


    public enum DoorType
    {
        None = 0,
        RearEntranceDoor = 1,
        ExteriorMainFloorDoor = 2,
        InteriorMainFloorDoor = 3,
        RearBreakRoomDoor = 4,
        ExteriorBasementDoor = 5,
        InteriorBasementDoor = 6,
        ManagedServicesDoor = 7,
        ManagedServicesBigDoor = 8
    }
}
```

Comment: When I click on any name in Gridview. I do not know how to loop through gridview to find 10 hours from first date and time.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on your row, retrieve your DateTime value. Then iterate over the rest of the rows (or a LINQ query) to find the next row with your "next" DateTime value that you're looking for.

Edit:
In your csvGridView_CellClick method, you retrieve the row index of the cell that was clicked. If you need to find the next occurrence for that person 10 hours later, get the startDate from the current row, which you are already doing. Once you have that, call a new method entitled "LocateNextEntryForPersonAtXDateTime(string personName, string targetDateTime)", something like this:

```
private int LocateNextEntryForPersonAtXDateTime(string personName, DateTime targetDateTime)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= csvGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
     if (csvGridView.Rows[i][0].Value.ToString().ToLower() == personName.ToLower()
       && Convert.ToDateTime(csvGridView.Cells[i][1].Value) >= targetDateTime)
         return i; // this is the row for the next entry when the person leaves
  }

  return -1; // not found
}
```

Comment: I need example have been working on this for weeks. The values are from a csv file and the door entries are by minutes need to narrow it down to hours.

Comment: Is the data bound to the data grid, or are you using a reader to load the datagrid?

Comment: @JayKlassen Added a method to my answer to show an example of searching for the next entry.

Comment: When I try that method it tells me that <= operator cannot be applied to int, and [] cannot be applied to indexing

Comment: Woops, targetDateTime parameter should be a DateTime, not string. Also, may need to change the Convert.ToDateTime method so instead of csvGridView.Rows, it should be csvGridView.Cells[i][1]...I'll update my answer to reflect. Also, I changed the csvGridView.Rows to csvGridView.Rows.Count

Comment: Nope still get errors, so very fusstrating that my school were morons and not teaching us every aspect of c#.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' C:\Documents and Settings\jklassen\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\excelCsvReader\excelCsvReader\Form1.cs 208 21 excelCsvReader

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere where you should be "setting" a value to an array, only retrieving values...